# ValueError: Array must not contain infs or nans

Tags: python

Hola necesito hacer un suavizado de linea, cuando lo compilo me sale mensaje

`ValueError: Array must not contain infs or nans.`

Deseo usar los datos del tx, mi código es el siguiente:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

col_1, col_2 = np.loadtxt('Mi_archivo'.txt, unpack=True, skiprows=1, usecols=[0,1])




x = np.array(col_1)
y = np.array(col_2)


x_smooth = np.linspace(x.min(),x.max(),1000)
y_smooth = make_interp_spline(x,y)(x_smooth)

plt.plot(x,y,color='red')
plt.plot(x_smooth,y_smooth,color='blue')
plt.show()
```

y mi archivo txt es el siguiente:

```
 Fechas         Monto
07-05-1990      450.50
08-05-1990      429.30
09-05-1990      398.20
10-05-1990      416.40
11-05-1990      350.50
12-05-1990      390.20
13-05-1990      258.10
14-05-1990      398.10
15-05-1990      400.20
16-05-1990      430.30
17-05-1990      350.20
18-05-1990      290.10
19-05-1990      289.20
```

¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿Y qué delimitador usas? No lo veo declarado en los argumentos, por lo tanto usa un espacio en blanco por defecto. ¿Están separadas las columnas por un espacio en blanco? Igual aquí hay un error: `np.loadtxt('Mi_archivo',txt ...)`. Creo que debería ser: `np.loadtxt('Mi_archivo.txt', ...)`. Verifica eso también. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras, ¿Que delimitador se puede usar?, ya esta editada esa parte.

Comment: El delimitador que vas a usar es el delimitador de tu archivo, si las columnas se separan entre si por un espacio entonces puedes dejar el delimitador por defecto, pero si son varios espacios, debes usar esa cantidad de espacios como delimitador (para 4 espacios: `delimiter = '    '`), y si es un tabulado entonces usas el tabulado como delimitador (`delimiter = '\t'`). Eso lo determinas de tu archivo de texto. Saludos

Comment: @Rocker, ¿pudiste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer uso de pandas y dataframes para realizar esto de una forma más sencilla.

Como indica @Mauricio en su comentario puedes hacer uso de un delimitador. Por ejemplo, usaré el tabulador para delimitar.

El fichero txt quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
Fechas  Monto
07-05-1990  450.50
08-05-1990  429.30
09-05-1990  398.20
10-05-1990  416.40
11-05-1990  350.50
12-05-1990  390.20
13-05-1990  258.10
14-05-1990  398.10
15-05-1990  400.20
16-05-1990  430.30
17-05-1990  350.20
18-05-1990  290.10
19-05-1990  289.20
```

- Leemos el fichero, colocamos el delimitador \t y colocamos como cabeceras 'Fechas' y 'Monto', es decir, la primera fila.

```
df = pd.read_csv('mi_archivo.txt', sep="\t", header = 0)
```

**Si imprimimos el contenido del dataframe**:

```
print(df)
```

**Tendremos**:

```
Fechas  Monto
07-05-1990  450.50
08-05-1990  429.30
09-05-1990  398.20
10-05-1990  416.40
11-05-1990  350.50
12-05-1990  390.20
13-05-1990  258.10
14-05-1990  398.10
15-05-1990  400.20
16-05-1990  430.30
17-05-1990  350.20
18-05-1990  290.10
19-05-1990  289.20
```

**Luego haces un plot indicando nombre del eje x e y**:

```
df.plot(x = 'Fechas', y = 'Monto')
plt.show()
```

**Código final**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('mi_archivo.txt', sep="\t", header = 0)

df.plot(x = 'Fechas', y = 'Monto')
plt.show()
```

**Resultado**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]